# SQL query get rows after and before number of days

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm inheriting an SQL query that gets data from my database table based on the number of days before the current date, I'd like to extend this functionality to also include data **after** the current date, I've tried extending it by adding a new line but my SQL query doesn't return any data, here's the current query:

```sql
SELECT
IF((
    SELECT
    send.id AS "true"
    FROM
    sends send
    WHERE
    send.sent = 0 AND
    send.subscription_id = subscription.id
    LIMIT 1
), true, false) AS already_queued
FROM
subscriptions subscription
WHERE
subscription.unsubscribed = 0 AND
subscription.source_id = 12 AND
DATE(subscription.date_added) <= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY
subscription.date_added
DESC
```

Right now it's the following line that handles the data after a number of days:

```sql
DATE(subscription.date_added) <= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Where **1** is replaced dynamically with the value, I now want to add a new line:

```sql
DATE(subscription.date_added) >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

So this should return data between the two dates but doesn't, what am I missing from the combined query to make it work:

```sql
SELECT
IF((
    SELECT
    send.id AS "true"
    FROM
    sends send
    WHERE
    send.sent = 0 AND
    send.subscription_id = subscription.id
    LIMIT 1
), true, false) AS already_queued
FROM
subscriptions subscription
WHERE
subscription.unsubscribed = 0 AND
subscription.source_id = 12 AND
DATE(subscription.date_added) >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
DATE(subscription.date_added) <= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY
subscription.date_added
DESC
```

Comment: MySQL is not MariaDB is not SQL Server. Please pick the ***one*** you are ***actually*** using.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will note this for next time.

Comment: So do you know what date range those expressions return? Does your table actually contain any records for that date range?